# Static method to take in object array and return a double

Tags: java, arrays

This is a homework question.

The requirement is to create 3 rectangle objects, put them in a rectangle array and create a static method that could add up the areas of the 3 rectangles in a total area.

What I managed to do was create an array for the area of rectangles in the main and add the inputs which worked but is not what the question demands

I moved the problematic code to the top.

edit: My main question is since rectangle array was made in main, how do i loop through it and add the areas outside of main. So the for loop

```
   public class Rectangle {
    
        
    //static meethod I'm trying to figure out
    
    public static double getTotalArea(Rectangle[] args){
        
        double total=0;
      
    for (int i = 0; i<rectangle_array.length; i++){
    total = total+ rectangle_array[i].getArea();
    }
    return total;
    }
    
    
    //main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    double total =0;
    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle (33, 8);
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle (9, 11);
    Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle (4, 20);
    
    Rectangle[] rectangle_array ={r1,r2,r3};
    
    /* 
    // this works fine, just not how they want me to do it
    double[] area_array = {r1.getArea(),r2.getArea(),r3.getArea()};
    
    for (int i = 0; i<area_array.length; i++){
    total = total+ area_array[i];
    }
    */
    
    System.out.println(getTotalArea(rectangle_array)); // i think this is how it would go
    }

// below is just instantating rectangles and whatnot------------------------------------
    
    double b; // base and height
    double h; 
        
    
    // 2 parameter constructor    
    public Rectangle(double b, double h){
        
            this.b = b;
            this.h = h;
        }
     
    //get area of one rectangle
    
    public double getArea(){
    return (b*h);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Good job on the full disclosure and getting started on a problem statement. Explain your specific problem, how it manifests itself, any errors, any output discrepancies.

Comment: "My main question is since rectangle array was made in main, how do i loop through it and add the areas outside of main" - the array was passed into the method via a parameter. I suggest you do reading on method parameters, basically. (Hint: in your method, use `args` instead of `rectangle_array` - although I'd suggest you rename the parameter anyway as `args` isn't very descriptive. I'd also strongly recommend that you read up on and follow Java naming conventions.)

Comment: yup that was it